# Where is the *goto line* command in Xcode4?

Tags: ide, xcode4

I couldn't find the goto line command in Xcode4. Where is it...?

Answer (score 139, accepted):

Either `Navigate -> Jump in "<mycurrentfile>"...` or <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

Comment: I can't see `Edit -> Go to line`, but ⌘L works. In Xcode4, ⌘L is tied to `Navigate -> Jump in "<mycurrentfile>"...`

Comment: +1 for shortcut. It works. But the menu has been removed, and replaced by the menu @DarkDust said.

Comment: Funny thing is on my system it also means "Quit from virtualized MacOS to native Windows, and lock the workstation" :-) After I remapped to the normal key sequence (Ctrl+G), works like a charm.

Comment: @Soonts Virtualized OSX on native Windows? Is it possible without violating EULA?

Comment: @Eonil, it is only possible without violating EULA if Windows is installed on Apple’s hardware. Which is not my case, BTW.